# Wicket Create New Tabs on Runtime

Tags: ajax, tabs, runtime, wicket

I've got a problem with creating new Tabs in Wicket on Runtime. When I add a new tab to the list of Tabs of my AjaxTabbedBar, I don't see any changes on the screen, maybe you can help me?

ExamplePage extends Webpage:

```
private AjaxTabbedPanel<AbstractTab> myTabBar;
tabs = new ArrayList<AbstractTab>();
        tabs.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<String>("Übersicht")) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Panel getPanel(String panelId) {
                if (myOverviewTab == null) myOverviewTab = new OverviewTab(panelId, getInstance());
                return myOverviewTab;
            }
        });

        tabs.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<String>("Details")) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Panel getPanel(String panelId) {
                if (myDetailTab == null) myDetailTab = new DetailTab(panelId);
                return myDetailTab;
            }
        });

        myTabBar = new AjaxTabbedPanel<AbstractTab>("tabs", tabs);
        add(myTabBar);
```

This is where I create the tabs on start and here comes my Runtimeaddition

```
public void newDetailTab(AjaxRequestTarget target){
    System.out.println("newDetailtab");
    tabs.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<String>("Details")) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Panel getPanel(String panelId) {
            return new DetailTab(panelId);
        }
    });
    myTabBar.setSelectedTab(myTabBar.getSelectedTab()+1);
    target.add(myTabBar);
}
```

So in the last line I want to change my actual tab, but actually it doesn't works. What makes me wonder is that the first tab has the number -1 (myTabBar.getSelectedtTab()), is this an error?

i also tried to update my tabbar with an AjaxRequestTarget, but there come different errors: cant update a page or Component with id [[tabs28]] was not found while trying to perform...

Hope you can help me.

edit: I found some people on google with an similiar problem, they tried to use LoadabledetachableModel... i just dont really know how to include this because its abstract, and i dont really know how to fill the methods these model wants to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i got it... Finally i had to use the AjaxRequestTarget from my function from the other class to refresh it directly... When i give that as a parameter there seems to be a fault. I think that this is the point but i'm not totally sure because i changed a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should add the new tab and then update the entire AjaxTabbedPanel with the AjaxRequestTarget.

"Cannot update component with id=XY" most of the time is indicating that you are missing `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)` on the component you are trying to update via ajax.

Comment: hm i added setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true) to myTabBar but nothing changed, same error...

Comment: one question about the ajaxrequesttarget: i also tried to get this via parameter while i call this function because the function where i call this has a target as parameter... is there a way to create a new target? Ajaxrequesttarget.get() doesnt work here because i use wicket 6.11

Comment: AjaxRequesttargets (ART) are available in Methods that use it. Meaning you should not try to "get" the ART from a static method but rather from the overwritten method parameters. You then add to the target all components that need updating. if a component is invisible (not in the markup) at invocation time you need to generate placeholders with the aforementioned method to enable wicket to find the components.

Comment: I also cannot see the part where you update your AjaxTabbedPanel in the question, can you please include that in the Question?

Comment: in the method public void newDetailTab(AjaxRequestTarget target), where do you get the target from? Where is this method called?

Comment: its called from another function #onClick from a ContextMenu... i just give this target what i get there as a parameter to #newDetailtab

Answer (score 0):

TabbedPanel starts out with -1 for its selected tab. On rending it will automatically select the first visible tab.

It seems to me you're working on a new TabbedPanel instance in #newDetailTab().

Comment: are you sure? because i just create the tabBar once... when i look at debug output comparing tabs in myTabBar before and after adding, it looks right... i think the problem is the pagerefresh, so i tried to do that with ajaxrequesttarget but i just get these errors...

Comment: Hm, i thought about these instances, maybe you are right, i dont know how java handle this: i call from this class TreeTable.java with a singleton parameter of itself, #newDetailtab is called from the TreeTable... In my mind this should be right, maybe java interprets this in another way...?